# PHP Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cakecrud\config\requirements.php on line 31

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

I have enabled both in `php.ini`

```
extension= intl
extension= php_intl.dll
```

Still the error is same when I run the command on cmd

Cake bake all students

Comment: Check that you modified the _correct_ php.ini, PHP embedded via the web server, and PHP executed via command line, often use different ones.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the ini settings?

Comment: yes I restarted the server afterwards @Marcel

Comment: How can I check via web server @CBroe . I am checking via php.ini in xampp

Comment: use oven to check your environment are ready, u also able to find the problem also can install cakephp oven https://github.com/CakeDC/oven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have added the intl exension to the wrong php.ini file.

It needs to be added to the web php.ini file, not cli.

To check what extensions are loaded for the web, write `phpinfo();exit;` in a PHP file then hit hit.

To see whats loaded in PHP cli (where you may have added it by mistake), run `php -m` at a terminal.

Comment: It displayed this after running php -m in a php terminal

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: intl is indeed not in that list, so whatever you did to enable it was not right.